# PHP video upload works on windows not in ios safari

Tags: php, linux, mp4

I'm using PHP to upload mp4 video files and generate thumbnails on Linux environment and I have no Idea why my code works fine on any windows browser but when using my ios safari I
get INVALID FILE.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php' ;

if($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"] != '')
{
 $data = explode(".", $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
 $extension = $data[1];
 $allowed_extension = array("mp4");
 if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension))
 {
  $name_only = pathinfo($_FILES["upload_file"]['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME) ; // Main Name Only 
  $new_video_name = $name_only.'.mp4';
  $new_img_name = $name_only.'.jpg';

  $path = $_POST["hidden_folder_name"] .'/'. $new_video_name;
  $img_path = $_POST["hidden_folder_name"] .'/'.$new_img_name ;
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], $path))
  {

    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',
    'timeout'          => 3600, 
    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12, 
));
            
    $video = $ffmpeg->open($path);
    $video->filters()->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 180))->synchronize();
    $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(5))->save($img_path);

   echo 'FILE UPLOADED';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'THERE IS AN ERROR';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'INVALID FILE';
 }
}
else
{
 echo 'PLEASE SELECT FILE';
}
```

Comment: That particular error comes from the else branch belonging to `if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension))` - so have you debugged these values yet ...?

Comment: Yes, you're right I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was causing the problem on ios Safari,

```
if(in_array($extension, $allowed_extension))
 {
```

Removing that and the

```
else
 {
  echo 'INVALID FILE';
 }
}
```

Fixed my problem.